# How to convert date string to NSDate in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I am getting date and time as string from web service those looks like date is "2013-10-29" and "11:30"(or "23:30") but I want show date like "29 OCT.2013" and Time is "11:30 AM"(or "11:30 PM").
I have gone through so many answers regarding this type of questions but when i tried its returning "null" without error or warings.Please help me out...

Comment: Please share code of what you have tried and possible links you have looked at we could just be telling you what you have already seen.

Comment: can you pls post the exact date string you want to convert in a NSDate object pls ?

Comment: I'd like to vote for closing this question as a duplicate. But there are so many duplicates that I can't decide which one to select. So please be more specific and provide details on what you've already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: This is simply duplicate of `NSDateFormatter` there is no need for any complex and extra calculation @tilo

Comment: @TheTiger this was more of a "you said you've gone through so many answers .. go on and you'll find the one that fits your specific problem."

Comment: @tilo Actually I'm unable to find any issue here. If anybody knows use of `NSDateFormatter` its very simple. And I'm sure 2-3 minutes R&D on google can solve this easily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply this code changing the manually coded time and date with your properties and It should work.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-29"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM.YYYY"];    
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatter];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate * timeNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"11:30"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];    
NSString * timeFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeNotFormatter];
```

The other option is put tighter time and date in one string and use this format:

```
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM.YYYY at hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: thanks alex nice v helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In first case your format will be: `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`, `@"HH:mm"`, and in the second one: `@"dd MMM.yyyy"`, `@"hh:mm a"`

Comment: NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM.YYYY "];
    NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc]init];
    date=[formatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-29"];                    and here date is returning "null"

Answer (score 0):

First of combine date & Time like "2013-10-29 11:30"

than  use the below function like [self dateFormat:@"yyyy-NN-dd HH:ss" newFormat:@"dd MMM.yyyy hh:mm a"]

```
- (NSString*) dateFormat : (NSString*)date currentFormat:(NSString*) currentFormat newFormat : (NSString*) newFormat
{
    NSString *dateStr = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:currentFormat];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:newFormat];
    NSString * strFinalDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];
    NSLog(@"%@",strFinalDate);

    [dtF release];
    [dateFormat release];

    return strFinalDate;
}
```

if you want Date and Time differ than separate it using NSArray.